# Use aggregate computations to obtain mean and std between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, aggregates

I have two dataframes: `df1` and `df2`. I want to use aggregates to obtain the `mean` and `std` between the s_values in both dataframes and put those results in a new dataframe called `new_df`

in `df1 =`

```
         statistics  s_values
year
1999  cigarette use       100
1999  cellphone use       310
1999   internet use       101
1999    alcohol use       100
1999       soda use       215
```

in `df 2 =`

```
         statistics  s_values
year
1999  cigarette use       156
1999  cellphone use       198
1999   internet use       232
1999    alcohol use       243
1999       soda use       534
```

The result that I am trying to get would look something like this.
desired output `new_df =`

```
         statistics  difference  mean  std
year
1999  cigarette use     56        ..    ..
1999  cellphone use    112        ..    ..
1999   internet use     78        ..    ..
1999    alcohol use    143        ..    ..
1999       soda use    319        ..    ..
```

I have managed to build a dataframe with a column with the difference in values using the code

```
new_df = df1.assign(Value=(df1['s_values'] - df2['s_values].abs())
new_df.rename(columns={'s_values':'difference'}, inplace=True)
```

this gives me this output but I do not know how to add the columns for the aggregate mean and std

```
         statistics  difference  
year
1999  cigarette use     56  
1999  cellphone use    112
1999   internet use     78 
1999    alcohol use    143 
1999       soda use    319
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: So when you say mean or standard deviation, it is for each statistics value. right ?

Comment: the mean and std are both one number,  do you want a column containing one value across the whole column for each? you can just call df[col].std() and df[col].mean() for those values... but I don't see why you would want a whole column for that?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for one number accross the entire column for each statistics. example one std for cigarette use, one for cellphone use, etc. Hope tthat makes sense I'm sorry for confusion

Comment: That is what i asked and you said, that is not what you want  ? Can you please provide a sample output, so that it is easier to understand what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding you right, you want to join the two dataframes and compute the mean and std dev

Can you try this?

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on= ['Year', 'statistics'])
df['mean']=df[['difference_x', 'difference_y']].mean(axis=1)
df['std'] = df[['difference_x', 'difference_y']].std(axis=1)
```

You could also try this if you want a groupby solution as mentioned in your comments

`pd.concat([df1[['difference']], df2[['difference']]]).groupby(level=0).std()`

`pd.concat([df1[['difference']], df2[['difference']]]).groupby(level=0).mean()`

Comment: I am getting KeyError: "None of [Index(['difference_x', 'difference_y'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Please check the columns names after you merge and use that in your mean and std computation. Can you try the groupby solution. It is using the original dataframe with the original columns

Comment: Sure, you can assign them like this `df['mean'] = pd.concat([df1[['difference']], df2[['difference']]]).groupby(level=0).mean()`